EasyAdminBundle ImageField: make images go to s3 bucket and not local folders
I am using PHP + Symfony and using EasyAdminBundle for my backoffice. In general I have defined an entity that has a field:
#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
private ?string $mainImage = null;

This was my ImageField:
ImageField::new('mainImage', 'Main image?')
    ->setBasePath('/uploads/images/page') // Adjust base path according to your setup
    ->setUploadDir('/public/uploads/images/page')
    ->setRequired(false)
    ->setHelp('Enter the main image'),

Now I am trying to replace this logic with s3 file upload. Has anyone do this? I am also trying to use Localstack locally, I have this docker compose setup there:
localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${S3_REGION}
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - localstack_data:/var/lib/localstack

So goal is to make sure images are landing in s3 and are being read from there

Create a custom easy admin field to handle storing image file in S3. Check how to create your own field (and look up image field to see how image are displayed) and implement your own that use S3.
